# O operador `else` não processa uma entrada de usuário incorreta

Tags: python-3.x

Estou fazendo um sistema de cadastro em Python.
O problema é que quando o usuário digita errado o seu sexo num `input`, o operador `else` acusa um erro.

```
from time import sleep  
while True:  
    print('\033[1;36m')  
    opcoes = '[1]- SE CADASTRAR\n[2]- TABUADA\n[3]- SAIR'  
    print(opcoes)  
    print('\033[m')  
    print('\033[1;37m')  
    op = int(input(''))  
    if op == 1:  
        nome = input('Crie um usuário: ')  
        senha = int(input('Crie uma senha com apenas números: '))  
        MF = str(input('Digite seu sexo: [M/F] ')).strip().upper()[0]  
    if MF == 'm' or 'M' or 'f' or 'F':  
        print('Sexo válido!')  
    else:  
        print('Sexo inválido!')  
    if op == 2:  
        numero = int(input('Digite um número: '))  
        for tab in range(1,11):  
            print('{} ×{:2} = {}'.format(numero,tab,numero*tab))  
    if op == 3:  
        print('\033[1;32m')  
        print('Saindo do script.')  
        sleep(2.5)  
        print('Loading...')  
        sleep(5.5)  
        print('Precione enter para sair.')  
        break  
        exit
```

Comment: Troque o declaração condicional `if MF == 'm' or 'M' or 'f' or 'F':` por `if MF in 'MF':`  .Não precisa testar com minúsculas pois aqui `MF = str(input('Digite seu sexo: [M/F] ')).strip().upper()[0]` MF retornará os caracteres convertido para maiúsculas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ocorre um erro no else por conta de um erro de sintaxe no seu if:

```
if MF == 'm' or 'M' or 'f' or 'F': 
    print('Sexo válido!') 
else: 
    print('Sexo inválido!')
```

o correto seria:

```
if MF == 'M' or MF == 'F':
    print('Sexo válido!')
else:
    print('Sexo inválido!')
```